# ASP.Net Core compile views in library project

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-mvc, pre-compilation

I have an asp.net core mvc project compiled as a dll:

`<OutputType>Library</OutputType>`

This project is referenced from a Windows Service project (classic .NET) and hosted inside it. This works well while I don't have views. The problem I have is when I add views which it tries to compile at runtime not finding the references.

What I thought is that, maybe, precompiling the views would fix the issue. But I can't seem to find the way to precompile the views for a "Library" output project.

Is there a way to precompile views for a Library type project in ASP.NET *core?

**Update:** Some more information. It seems that the targets to precompile the views only work with Exe outputs because they expect to have a `.exe` and `.exe.config` files generated; this does not happen for a "Library" project (as it only generates a `.dll` file) and the building of the `.PrecompiledViews.dll` fails.

Answer (score 0):

There are as named [`View components`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components) in `ASP.NET Core`. So yes, you can create library with your view components and share them between your UI projects. Check this post for the details - [Loading View Components from a Class Library in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2016/07/16/loading-view-components-from-a-class-library-in-asp-net-core.aspx)

> New to `ASP.NET Core MVC`, view components are similar to partial views,
>   but they're much more powerful. View components don't use model
>   binding, and only depend on the data provided when calling into it. A
>   view component:
>
> - Renders a chunk rather than a whole response.
> - Includes the same separation-of-concerns and testability benefits found between a controller and view.
> - Can have parameters and business logic.
> - Is typically invoked from a layout page.

Comment: I think I have not explained my issue very well... :) The problem I have is that I need to have my asp.net core project deploying a dll but at the same time precompiling the views. View precompilation only works for me with an "Exe" type output.

Comment: Did you have a chance to check this? http://www.iaspnetcore.com/Blog/BlogPost/593df8ea84cd453ecc6d8a26/aspnet-core-precompiling-razor-views